# Can cURL be used to send emails through a proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy, localhost, mail-server

I would like to send mails from my localhost. I am connected to internet through my institute's proxy(HTTP) which requires authentication. Is it possible to use cURL to send mails, because so far i've seen it fetching webpages only. If not so, could you please specify any other alternatives? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: cUrl is a http client, not an smtp client, so no, using curl to send e-mails won't work

Comment: could we use it in conjunction with pearmail or something similar....problem is: i have to go through a proxy and I am not able to configure smtp servers for that...

Comment: And your institute doesn't have an SMTP server you can use to send mails? Or does it use SMTP auth? In the latter case, just use a mail lib to send mails instead of using the PHP `mail` function (because that doesn't support SMTP auth).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send mails using a web interface, you can script curl to use the proxy and the web site: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

If you want to use SMTP, curl can do that too. It might however not be the best tool out there for sending emails.

I don't think anyone truly access SMTP through HTTP proxy even if I think you can for example tunnel through a HTTP proxy (with CONNECT) using curl if you really want to.